# Error 500 PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, error500

Estoy tratando de solucionar un problema de error 500 que me da el servidor donde tengo alojada la web

El error no me da mayor información. Tengo la siguiente duda: La tabla la cual consulto en la base tiene por nombre IM_Usuarios y yo en el PHP la consulto de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql_query = "select * from im_usuarios";
```

Puede ser que al hacer la consulta en minúscula el script me falle ?

Comment: Abre el log de errores ahí se grabó el error generado

Comment: no se mucho de php, pero me huele a que esa no es la manera de realizar una query en el, la [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) me hace pensar que lo tienes mal

Comment: Estas obersvando un error que debido al navegador cuando intenta abrir el archivo .php no encuentra el archivo en el servidor, tal vez este siendo que no reconoce el nombre modificado o la ruta especifica donde esta dicho archivo. 

como dice revisa el log del server @BetaM y verfica que error y por favor expande la explicación de tu pregunta.

Comment: @Kinslert si ese fuera el caso entonces el error sería un 404

Comment: Como indicó BetaM, debería verificar el log de tu servidor, y en cuanto a tu duda sobre la consulta sql, no, no debe dar error al consultar los nombres de tablas en minusculas o mayusculas.

Comment: Al final el problema fue el nombre de la TABLA

Comment: @Jellestad publica tu solución entonces

Comment: el Error 500 es internal, del servidor, 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

El problema ya fue resuelto surgió a partir del nombre de la tabla que en conjunto con ORM como Propel y Doctrine combinados con versiones desactualizadas de php, generan el error ya comentado. Esto también influye sin utilizar ORM.

Entonces la solución es siempre utilizar el nombre y las columnas de las tablas tal cual el nombre, si tiene mayúscula lo ponemos con mayúscula y si es en minúscula lo ponemos en min.